# Conditional Vuejs Click Event Binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I only want to add a click event when `!date.disabled || date.availability === 'none'`. How can I do that?

```
<div class="relative h-20 border border-gray-100 sm:h-24" 
  @click="!date.disabled || date.availability !== 'none' ? selectDate(date) : null">
  {{date}}
</div>
```

Comment: perhaps put the condition in `(!date.disabled || date.availability !== 'none')`? and instead of `null` do something like `() =>{}` (if that's the problem) ... thing is, you never said what is wrong with the code you posted - should we guess?

Comment: Why would someone make that a "code snippet" when it clearly won't run

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry about that. Actually the problem I face is when `date.availability` is `none` the event is fired but when `!date.disabled` is true the event is not fired and I also tried by wraping the `||` condition in parenthesis but still the event is fired when `date.availability` is `none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just try `<button @click="(!date.disabled || date.availability !== 'none') ? selectDate() : null">Greet</button>`

[Working Fiddle](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9kctOwzAQRX9laiGlldpkH6UFJCT4AlZe1E0n4OKMI3tShNr8O+OkRTwkdp6Hj++9Pqn7rsuPPapSVbEOtmOIyH230WTbzgeGEwRsYIAm+BYyWc00aao9RQYyLcI6Lcyz5x7zQ8wW19ne8HV20gSwt9HsHO5LaIyLuEw9czTWmZ11lj9K0Io8oVaaBqFoanqq2XoSRQ5rfhDgfAEjzDgMPN8+oXMebk5JR340rsdhtpW7g6aqmOyIESkY287J/VRxteuZBXtXO1u/rbWaz5LY/KoQzudRff5dHszWa8iSwGwBtz8llUC9c1ptHgMiV8XEl7eq4uthtVRToKvWdBKUJ4l89KIvg6hVOblLPQk61Vq9MnexLIrY1OmjDjH34aWQUx56YivGMbarXfDvEYOAtRqjvTAKaR4xrALSHgOG/5i/Vv9wE1aSHdTwCagYxe0=)

Comment: Thanks for an Idea and now It's working on my side

Comment: @WaleedTariq Can you approve this answer if this works for you.?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it by using an `AND` (`&&`) operator without using ternary operator.

```
@click="(!date.disabled || date.availability !== 'none') && selectDate(date)"
```

If condition passed then only `selectDate` method will get trigger else nothing will happen.

Comment: Jindal Your solution is working fine as well. Thanks